# Get list of entities by list of id's - IN ORDER

Tags: linq, entity-framework

See this question/answer: [Entity Framework: Get all rows from the table for the ids in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21731461/entity-framework-get-all-rows-from-the-table-for-the-ids-in-list)

Now my question: I would like to get the entities sorted as they are in the list of id's.

I would be dealing with a small list, and don't mind if it's sorted in memory after pulling list from db.

Comment: You need to choose a Property to sort by and pass it as a lambda expression to OrderByDescending

like:

.OrderByDescending(x => x.Delivery.SubmissionDate);

Comment: Sorted by the integer? [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) should do the trick

Comment: I want to sort by the order that the items are in the list of id's.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
var result = db.table
  .Where(l => ids.Any(id => id == l.id))
  .ToList()
  .OrderBy(l => ids.IndexOf(l.id));
```

or

```
var result = db.table
  .Where(l => ids.Contains(l.id))
  .ToList()
  .OrderBy(l => ids.IndexOf(l.id));
```

both should work fine.

Comment: Thank you. now for a bonus if it can be sorted at the db ;)

Comment: It can be sorted at the database, but it is so bad performance wise, I'm not going to show it and have other people copy it and use it.

Comment: Does this have any limit on the number of items in the INT list? Can i pass a list of 2000 id values and make a call like this?

Comment: It might depending on the version of EF you are working with.  I would test with 2200